# Scaling of Units from double to float

Tags: python

Below is my output and the value is represented in scaled units like below.

Default value: 2.000000e-02

When ever the value is represented as double(like above), I would like to convert and print like a  floating value(0.02)
Expected Output
Default value: 0.02

Could anyone pls help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Format strings are the correct choice for this task I think. The `.2f` specifies that the number should be converted into fixed-point notation and have exactly two digits after the decimal point. Example:

```
d = 2.000000e-02
print("{:.2f}".format(d))
```

Output:

```
0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called *string formatting*. `%` and `.format` are used for this task, [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/) has explanation and comparison of boths. In this case you might easily use either, that is to get 2 digits after . you might do

```
x = 2.000000e-02
print('%.2f' % x)  # 0.02
print('{:.2f}'.format(x))  # 0.02
```

Alternatively you might use so-called f-strings (requires `python3.6` or newer) that is

```
x = 2.000000e-02
print(f'{x:.2f}')  # 0.02
```

Consult your organization style guidelines to detect which one you should use.